# Pyspark join with functions and difference between timestamps

Tags: apache-spark, join, databricks, pyspark

I am trying to join 2 tables with user events. I want to join table_a with table_b by user_id (id) and when the difference timestamps smaller than 5s (5000ms).

Here is what I am doing:

```
table_a = (
  table_a
  .join(
  table_b,
    table_a.uid == table_b.uid 
     & abs(table_b.b_timestamp - table_a.a_timestamp) < 5000 
     & table_a.a_timestamp.isNotNull()
  ,
  how = 'left'
  )
)
```

I am getting 2 errors:

Error 1) 
`ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.`

Error 2 when if I remove the 2nd condition on the join and leave only the 1st and 3rd:
`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;(`uid`AND (`a_timestamp`IS NOT NULL))&#39; due to data type mismatch: differing types in &#39;(`uid`AND (`a_timestamp`IS NOT NULL))&#39; (string and boolean).;;`

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Your conditions needs parantheses (Ex. ((condtion1) & (condition2) & ..). It is a common issue with pyspark. For the second error you should consider first filling NA with 0 values and on the second condition parsing your two timestamp values as double, decimal, integer or anything same. Then you can just use not equal to zero for your last condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need parentheses around each filtering condition. For example, the following works:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 20),
    (1, 21),
    (1, 25),
    (1, 30),
    (2, 21),
], ['id', 'val'])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
    (1, 21),
    (2, 30),
], ['id', 'val'])

df1.join(
    df2, 
    (df1.id == df2.id) 
    & (abs(df1.val - df2.val) < 5)
).show()
# +---+---+---+---+
# | id|val| id|val|
# +---+---+---+---+
# |  1| 20|  1| 21|
# |  1| 21|  1| 21|
# |  1| 25|  1| 21|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

But without parens:

```
df1.join(
    df2, 
    df1.id == df2.id
    & abs(df1.val - df2.val) < 5
).show()
# ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Comment: Nailed it! Was bound to lose a few more hours before I found this one.
Many thanks.